# A platfom dependency on android is added to package-lock.json

Tags: node.js, npm

In [our project](https://github.com/ecadlabs/taquito), on a specific computer when I remove `website/package-lock.json` and `npm i` and then commit the `website/package-lock.json` into the repository, it fails in the CI with the following error:

```
Run npm ci
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for @esbuild/android-arm@0.16.17: wanted {"os":"android","arch":"arm"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    android
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  arm
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
```

That computer is not arm. Is Fedora linux 37 on AMD 64 cpu, with node version 16.x and npm 8.x. Where does this `android` platform dependency come from?

This does not happen on all computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error. It was resolved by upgrading `netlify-cli` to v14

I've traced the error to `netlify-cli`

- this bug ticket: https://github.com/netlify/cli/issues/5323#issue-1502009992
- this insightful article: https://www.justus.pw/posts/2023-02-10-fix-netlify-cli-npm-install.html at this time

The issue on netlify/cli is now closed with a comment stating that v14 have resolved the issue

And indeed bumping the version in my package.json resolved the issue and I can now run `npm ci`

If you can't upgrade to that version it is said v`12.2.8` is the last version where `npm ci` worked